# Function only works when I have php debug listener on

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, phpstorm

I am trying to write a function which gets data from the database and writes it in my Excel sheet. It worked great yesterday (it output the Excel file and downloaded it from my browser), but today when I opened PhpStorm and tried to fire the function it seemed to not work.

When I put my listener on for PHP debug connections it suddenly worked. I haven't encountered such problems before.

Does it have to do with the listener refreshing my TMP files? Note that I haven't set the debugger class in my function. I am only talking about the php debug listener from PhpStorm.

Comment: What Listening for incoming connection does: it makes PhpStorm listen port 9000. I don't see how this could affect the execution. What do you mean by "it seemed to now work"? What exactly happened?

Comment: it seemed to not work i said. After restarting my computer. It kept working. It might have been a bug or something. Everytime I stopped the listener and executed the function the program would give errors. Right now it's working fine since I restarted. I still have no clue how this was happening.